# I need help displaying a graph from user input in an applet

Tags: java, swing, input, graph, applet

I am lost on how to use the user input to create a graph after they click on the calculate button.  I am new to programming and a push in the right direction would be really nice.

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class worksheet5 extends JApplet implements ActionListener {

   double E, B, N;
   JLabel title, firstBalance, lastBalance, userBalance1, userBalance2,
         userBalance3, userBalance4, rateInvested, rateOfReturn;

   JTextField begBalance, endBalance, balance1, balance2, balance3, balance4,
         userRate, userReturn;
   Button b;

   public void init() {
      setLayout(new BorderLayout());
      setUpTitle();
      setUpMiddle();
      setUpBottom();
   }

   public void setUpTitle() {
      title = new JLabel("Calculate your return rate", JLabel.CENTER);
      add(title, BorderLayout.NORTH);
   }

   public void setUpMiddle() {

      firstBalance = new JLabel("What was your starting balance?");
      begBalance = new JTextField("", 15);
      userBalance1 = new JLabel("What was your balance after year one?");
      balance1 = new JTextField("", 15);
      userBalance2 = new JLabel("What was your balance after year two?");
      balance2 = new JTextField("", 15);
      userBalance3 = new JLabel("What was your balance after year three?");
      balance3 = new JTextField("", 15);
      userBalance4 = new JLabel("What was your balance after year four?");
      balance4 = new JTextField("", 15);
      lastBalance = new JLabel("What was your ending balance year five?");
      endBalance = new JTextField("", 15);
      rateInvested = new JLabel("How many years did you invest?");
      userRate = new JTextField("", 15);

      JPanel pane1 = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());
      pane1.add(firstBalance);
      pane1.add(begBalance);
      JPanel pane2 = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());
      pane2.add(userBalance1);
      pane2.add(balance1);
      pane2.add(userBalance2);
      pane2.add(balance2);
      pane2.add(userBalance3);
      pane2.add(balance3);
      pane2.add(userBalance4);
      pane2.add(balance4);
      pane2.add(lastBalance);
      pane2.add(endBalance);
      JPanel pane3 = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());
      pane3.add(rateInvested);
      pane3.add(userRate);

      JPanel mainPane = new JPanel(new GridLayout(3, 1));
      mainPane.add(pane1);
      mainPane.add(pane2);
      mainPane.add(pane3);
      add(mainPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
   }

   public void setUpBottom() {

      rateOfReturn = new JLabel("Your rate of return is :");
      userReturn = new JTextField("", 15);
      b = new Button("calculate");
      b.addActionListener(this);
      JPanel pane4 = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());
      pane4.add(rateOfReturn);
      pane4.add(userReturn);
      pane4.add(b);
      add(pane4, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
   }

   public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
      if (ae.getSource() == b) {
         E = Double.parseDouble(endBalance.getText());
         B = Double.parseDouble(begBalance.getText());
         N = Double.parseDouble(userRate.getText());
         double R = Math.pow(E / B, 1.0 / N) - 1;

         userReturn.setText("" + R * 100 + "%");

      }
   }
}

class BarChart extends worksheet5 {
   int n;
   String year[];
   int value[];

   public void graph() {
      n = 5;
      year = new String[n];
      value = new int[n];

      year[0] = getParameter("year0");
      year[1] = getParameter("year1");
      year[2] = getParameter("year2");
      year[3] = getParameter("year3");
      year[4] = getParameter("year4");

      value[0] = Integer.parseInt(begBalance.getText());
      value[1] = Integer.parseInt(balance1.getText());
      value[2] = Integer.parseInt(balance2.getText());
      value[3] = Integer.parseInt(balance3.getText());
      value[4] = Integer.parseInt(balance4.getText());

   }

   public void paint(Graphics g) {
      Font font = new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 15);
      g.setFont(font);
      for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
         g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
         g.drawString(year[i], 20, i * 50 + 30);
         g.setColor(Color.RED);
         g.fillRect(70, i * 50 + 10, value[i], 40);
         g.drawString(String.valueOf(value[i]) + "%", 180, i * 50 + 35);
      }

      String msg = "Bar Chart from Year 2001 - 2005";
      g.setColor(Color.darkGray);

      font = new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 20);
      g.setFont(font);
      g.drawString(msg, 50, 300);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Suggestions:

- Your worksheet5 class should be renamed WorkSheet5 so as to comply with [Java naming conventions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naming_convention_(programming)#Java). Variable names should all begin with a lower letter while class names with an upper case letter. Also you should avoid using trivial variable names such as `b` or `s` unless they are being used for trivial purposes such as the index of a for loop. Instead use names that have some meaning so that your code becomes self-commenting. Following these suggestions as well as following good code formatting practices will allow others (such as us!) to better understand your code, and more importantly, will allow your future self to better understand just what you were thinking 6 months ago when you wrote the code.
- BarChart should not extend worksheet5 but should extend JPanel.
- You should draw in BarChart's paintComponent method override
- And use the `@Override` annotation prior to this method to be sure that it is a valid override.
- The first line of your `paintComponent(Graphics g)` method override should be a call to the super's method to allow Java to clean up any dirty pixels: `super.paintComponent(g);`
- You will extract the data from the text fields in the ActionListener, not in BarChart. You will then pass the data into a BarChart instance.
- Give BarChart a constructor that takes in the numbers that it will use to create graphics.
- Then use those numbers in its paintComponent method where you try to draw your bars.
- Then display the BarChart JPanel somewhere, possibly in the current applet using a CardLayout, possibly in a JOptionPane.

Comment: Wow this was a really nice push in the right direction!

Comment: I must be stupid.  I changed my code in the ActionListener.  I am confused with the passing of data. fourth bullet point.  I am a noob. sorry

Comment: @MattMiddaugh: don't beat yourself up -- that's your teacher's responsibility. Most important, is your code working or getting closer to functioning?

Comment: I have everything working until I have to pass data to the bar chart.  I dont know how to pass the information to the BarChart.